# Strict Standards variables should be passed by reference

Tags: javascript, php, variables, upload

I have a problem with the upload script code.

**Error:**

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/user/public_html/upload.php on line 67

This is 67th line in `upload.php`:

```
$type = end(explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['fisiere']['name'])));
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: php doesn't like nesting calls. put each call on it's own line in PHP

Answer (score 0):

end() should be used on a concrete variable not on the result of a function like explode():

```
$typeArray = explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['fisiere']['name']));
$type = end($typeArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only variables can be passed by reference, so try this:

```
$value = explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['fisiere']['name']));
$type = end($value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$typeArray = explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['fisiere']['name']));
$type = end($typeArray);
```